# Hive | Unable to create a partitioned table | ParseException

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to create a partitioned table from the Hive CLI,

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stocks (
   ymd             STRING,
   price_open      FLOAT, 
   price_high      FLOAT,
   price_low       FLOAT,
   price_close     FLOAT,
   volume          FLOAT,
   price_adj_close FLOAT
 )
 PARTITIONED BY (exchange STRING, symbol STRING)
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

But the terminal throws an exception instead "ParseException".

The error dump,

```
NoViableAltException(100@[])
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.identifier(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:11545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.identifier(HiveParser.java:44551)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameType(HiveParser.java:38215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameTypeList(HiveParser.java:36417)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.tablePartition(HiveParser.java:32852)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.createTableStatement(HiveParser.java:4922)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:2364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1062)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1158)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1037)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:756)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:615)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
FAILED: ParseException line 10:17 cannot recognize input near 'exchange' 'STRING' ',' in column specification
```

Any clue what I am missing here? The syntax looks impeccable :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange is a keyword in hive. You have to use a different name for your partition column.